# How to customize flyout page top bar in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp

I want to customize top bar of Xamarin forms like following i want to add some of menus search-bar and profile icon with drop down
[image: example image is here]

I am trying to achieve this with flyoutpage control.

Please help me to achieve the result first

Comment: maybe this code can give you more insight https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/Navigation/FlyoutPage

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `NavigationPage.TitleView` to achieve this. Remember to remove the `Title` of the `ContentPage`.

Please refer to the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
                   x:Class="FlyoutPageNavigation.ContactsPage"
                  >

    <NavigationPage.TitleView >
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" MinimumWidthRequest="200">
            <Label Text="test"  Margin="10,0,10,0"></Label>
            <SearchBar Text="please input key words" BackgroundColor="Yellow" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"    ></SearchBar>
        </StackLayout>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>
      <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout>
                  <Label Text="Contacts data goes here" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
            </StackLayout>
      </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**Update:**

> i want the common titleview for all. It will take a while for me to do
> for all pages.

You can create common contentview for all the pages.

1.create a ContentView (`CustomTitleView`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="FlyoutPageNavigation.CustomTitleView">
  <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" MinimumWidthRequest="200">
            <Label Text="custom contentview"   Margin="10,0,10,0"></Label>
            <SearchBar Text=" key words" BackgroundColor="Yellow" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"    ></SearchBar>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

2.add this `CustomTitleView` to `Application.Resources` of file `App.xaml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:flyoutpagenavigation="clr-namespace:FlyoutPageNavigation"
             x:Class="FlyoutPageNavigation.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <flyoutpagenavigation:CustomTitleView x:Key="CustomTitleView"/>

        <Style TargetType="ContentPage" x:Key="CustomPage">
            <Setter Property="NavigationPage.TitleView" Value="{StaticResource CustomTitleView}"/>
        </Style>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

3.add  `Style="{StaticResource CustomPage}"` to all pages:

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
                   x:Class="FlyoutPageNavigation.ContactsPage"
             
                 Style="{StaticResource CustomPage}"
                  >

    <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout>
                  <Label Text="Hi" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
            </StackLayout>
      </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: First thank you to reach out my question. That's an okay solution but what if i had multiple views in them i want the common titleview for all. It will take a while for me to do for all pages.

Comment: `i want the common titleview for all.` You can try to use `ContentView` to achieve this. Please check my updated answer.